# finding current url and splitting them into parts and checking if there is index.php or not in the url

Tags: php, arrays

I am suffering from a problem while i take the current url of the page and spliting them into parts and then checking for the index.php phrase.So far i have done this:

```
  <?php
      $domain=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
      $values = parse_url($domains);
  $path = explode('/',$values['path']);
  if(array_search($path[2], "index.php"))
        {
          echo "hello";
        }
  ?>
```

but its not working so guys help me out and thank you in advance coz i know i will be satisfied by your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$pathToFile = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

$currentFilename = substr($pathToFile, strrpos($pathToFile, '/') + 1);

if($currentFilename == 'index.php')
{
    echo 'This file is index.php!';
}
```

1. `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` is the path to the current file on the local system. Since you don't care about the domain name or the query string, this is easier.
2. `strrpos($pathToFile, '/')` gets the index of the last occurrence of `/` in `$pathToFile`.
3. `substr($pathToFile, strrpos($pathToFile, '/') + 1)` get the portion of `$pathToFile` starting with the character after the index found by `strrpos()` in step 2.
4. You should be left with only the filename in `$currentFilename`, which you can compare with whatever you choose.

Note that this will match *any* `index.php` file, not just the one at your domain root. For example, if your site is located at `http://example.com`, `http://example.com/subdir/index.php` would also be true for `$currentFilename == 'index.php'`. If that's not what you want, you'd do it a little differently.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$domain=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$path = explode('/',$domain);
if(array_search($path[2], "index.php"))
    {
      echo "hello";
    }
```

I'm not sure what `parse_url()` is, but it didn't seem to do anything in your code.